# How to compare data on two excel sheets with VBA code?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Sample data set:
[image]

Is there a VBA formula that will compare the dates, and the similar words, between the two data sets? For example, if it contains "Ter" and "1/9/18", then I can find out that the location is "Grass".

My goal is to find the cells where the "Dates" are the same and where "Away or Home Club" matches "Organization", to ultimately find the location.

I have two excel sheets and I need to find the rows which are comparable. I have a "Date" column that needs to be an exact match on both sheets. In addition I have two columns and need to match up with one column on the second sheet. (They are not exact matches, but both include similar words for example, "Ter").

[Sample Workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEv8r.png)

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1407605/edit) to include sample data, expected result and what you've tried so far

Comment: Can you please mock up an example of the expected result and explain the logic? It's not clear what you want to achieve. Also, there is no Excel worksheet function that does a fuzzy match for text. You would need complicated VBA for that.

Comment: (1) As cybernetic.nomad said, please *show expected results.*  I guess you want results in Column H; e.g., H6 = “Grass”.  And, based on my guess of what you want, only four of the nine values you have in Column G would have results — am I missing something?  (2) Will you be dealing only with initial substrings (e.g., “Ter” is the first three letters of “Terps”), or might there be middle strings (e.g., “ants”, “nights” or “arg”)?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (3) “Ter” (in Column G) is a substring of “Terps” (in Column B), but “Eag” (in Column C) is a substring of “Eagles” (in Column G).  Are you serious?  You want to do substring matching in both directions? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data set has no duplicate dates, and each team name has a unique three-character identifier. For data meeting those constraints, this will work. For more than one contest per date, there may not be a worksheet function solution.

[image]

```
`=IF(OR(UPPER(LEFT(INDEX(Data1,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$10,0),2),3))=UPPER(LEFT(G2,3)),UPPER(LEFT(INDEX(Data1,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$10,0),3),3))=UPPER(LEFT(G2,3))),INDEX(Data1,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$10,0),4),"no match")`
```

I named the range $A$2:$D$10 'Data1' for simplicity.

We account for the matching text by taking `UPPER(LEFT([text],3))`.

This follows the general outline:

`=IF(OR([one_thing],[another_thing]),[do_something],[something_else])`

[one_thing], excluding the upper and left text manipulation, expands to:

`INDEX(Data1,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$10,0),2)=G2`

and [another_thing], similarly:

`INDEX(Data1,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$10,0),3)=G2`

Those say, using the date (`F2`) as a key, search the data set and bring back the 2nd and 3rd columns' values, respectively, and compare to `G2`.

If there's a match, [do_something]:

`INDEX(Data1,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$10,0),4)`

Get the 4th column of the data set record where the date matches, and print it; otherwise

[something_else]

`"no match"`

You could wrap with an `IFERROR` to eliminate the #N/A results for rows where there's no matching date in the data set, if you want.

Comment: Thank you!! That was exactly what I was looking for!!! Unfortunately, my data set does have duplicate dates. You mentioned there is not something I can add to the formula to account for that?

Comment: Not with this approach. This approach relies on, basically, finding a matching date in the data set and then double checking that that date also contains a matching team name. To do something over multiple date matches, you're basically doing a `FOR` loop, you're doing VBA. It's possible to do with a worksheet function but, really, it would be prohibitively complex.

Comment: ...Which is fine, VBA is fine, I'm just not practiced enough with it to be qualified to use it to write an answer on SuperUser. All the VBA I've written is cribbed from existing code I found on SuperUser to begin with. Maybe edit your question to add a VBA tag and one of the resident whizzes will be along to show you how it's done - this is an easy task in VBA.

Comment: Thanks, Alex! I really appreciate all your time and help with this!

Comment: Hi Alex, I was wondering if the formula you provided would work if I combine the cells to get rid of the duplicate dates. I can do so on both columns if need be. For example, something like the attached picture. I know it won't tell me which location for which game, but it will at least eliminate the dates where the location is not available (less I have to manually check).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, Jamie. I mean, how big is your data set? How many duplicate dates are there? There are lots of options if the alternative is manually doing work yourself, and you're willing to do a bit of "smooshing" to get the answers you need. The formula I provided will compare an identifier in column F to data in column A, and for matches will look for column G in columns B and C, then return column D. The characteristics of the data itself doesn't matter.

Comment: I have 3,558 data points and 219 unique dates. The formula you provided seems like it would work (at least one step closer by eliminating the ones that don't match at all), if I am able to combine the cells for duplicated dates. For example, on the picture attached above, if we could find duplicate dates in column A and then combine the values in column B, C, and D. The same for finding duplicates in column F and combining column G and H. And then using the formula you provided earlier? Would that work? Was that clear?

Comment: No. This simplistic approach is wholly unsuited for data of that description. VBA or an array formula would work. At this point your best bet is probably to post a new question that includes the information you've provided me here in these comments. You'll also get a better reception if you show that you've done some work/research to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score -1):

The first solution would be to develop VBA code to do what you want.

An alternative would be to extract 2 CSV files and to compare them using WinMerge.

The best solution depend of the complexity of your search.

Before comparing the 2 files, you can load them using Notepad++ and use specific Regex to remove non significant rows.